# Import local modules

Tags: go, module

I am importing local go modules, but I keep getting these error messages:

`main.go:6:2: unknown import path "github.com/getset0/kamona/database": cannot find module providing package github.com/getset0/kamona/database
client.go:5:2: unknown import path "github.com/getset0/kamona/kauth": cannot find module providing package github.com/getset0/kamona/kauth`

Those files are located at my project root dir, and my go.mod is as follow:

```
module github.com/getset0/kamona

require (
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.2.0
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.5.1
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.1.2
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20181114220301-adae6a3d119a
    golang.org/x/vgo v0.0.0-20180912184537-9d567625acf4 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.16.0
)

replace github.com/getset0/kamona/kauth => ./kauth

replace github.com/getset0/kamona/database => ./database
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use the following commands in order to download missing packages
**go get -u -v github.com/getset0/kamona/database**
and
**go get -u -v github.com/getset0/kamona/kauth**

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `go.mod` files in `./kauth` and `./database`?

Normally the `go.mod` goes at the root of the project (which would be `github.com/getset0/kamona`). This would also imply you do not need to `require` `github.com/getset0/kamona/kauth` or `github.com/getset0/kamona/database`.

This also implies that you don't need the `replace` statements.

Comment: Yeah, I was not pushing my diff to the github, and that was the problem. Thanks for your help